# Parameters typings based off given key

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

I am trying to add typings to my Settings screen - which includes Settings like text, checkbox etc.
However, how do I detect the typings based off my key value.

```
export interface ISettingsType {
    title: string;
    key: string;
}

export interface ISettingSwitchType extends ISettingsType {
    type: "switch";
    value: boolean;
}

export interface ISettingTextType extends ISettingsType {
    type: "text";
    value: string;
}

export type SingleSetting = ISettingSwitchType | ISettingTextType;

export interface SettingsState {
    [key: string]: SingleSetting;
}

const settings: SettingsState = {
    one: {
        title: "1",
        type: "switch",
        value: false,
        key: "1",
    },
    two: {
        title: "2",
        type: "text",
        value: "bad",
        key: "2",
    },
}

function changeSetting({key, value}: Pick<SingleSetting, "key"|"value">) {
    settings[key].value = value;
}

changeSetting({ key: "one", value: "test"})
console.log(settings);
```

Right now, I can change the value of "one" to a string even though it is supposed to be a boolean.
Thank you so much.

[TS-Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBASwHY2FAZgQwMbDgSQGVgYZkBzAZwBUBPMPAbwCgBIMmAG2AC45KYUCgG42Aa2C0%20AoUnKiAvs2ahIsRCjRZcBYqQqEA7ghjYAFnQZxQqJABNKukmTk16TNjHd8ARJWOmZj6irABumJwArrxwAEYQENyYSIrKqtDwyKgYOHhEzhTUNpZ4NsD2jvn6riVwLOzecD6oIDDBbOFRMTIizEoq4BlwXlaEFNx6LuRwALxO1eRGJua1AD7zU0WtJaIDapmaOTqTFJSEMJiodWwA2hJS-IIUALp8Y3ITBXKpzNgQSAJ%20F8qG9gWcLlc5iw4DC4P8YtDYUiONxfABGHwAGmYSORjT8AXMWJxuJhnWifCwnEowGxpJh93RxNYCmx7EMED4iNJKJiPgATMT6cN8S02nT6eS%20bFMHYhfTGU1BWzWX1lFktLk4CdXAAFTBQTAAW0cLDVzHQkSQ2DI-zg5mS5GAOvIAApGPdMXApQo%20LqENgxAAed7kT4LL0%20e4%20VY%20KU%20AB8AEprkiaQtKHdJM8AHRS2beiLRH4OuTO4HuuCKnzwrGFrq%20ThGzAQHwKJO-f6URLAHOcCBu9NTShJ4RAA)

Comment: TS playground link is broken, and I still don't understand what you're trying to accomplish here. Please provide more context.

Answer (score 0):

```js
export interface ISettingsType {
    title: string;
    key: string;
}

export interface ISettingSwitchType extends ISettingsType {
    type: "switch";
    value: boolean;
}

export interface ISettingTextType extends ISettingsType {
    type: "text";
    value: string;
}

export type SingleSetting = ISettingSwitchType | ISettingTextType;

export type SettingsState<META extends { key: string; type: 'switch' | 'text' }[]> = {
    [key in META[number]['key']]: SingleSetting & { type: (META[number] & { key: key })['type'] };
}



const settings: SettingsState<
    [
        { key: 'one', type: 'switch' },
        { key: 'two', type: 'text' }
    ]
> = {
    one: {
        title: "1",
        type: "switch",
        value: false,
        key: "1",
    },
    two: {
        title: "2",
        type: "text",
        value: "bad",
        key: "2",
    },
};

function changeSetting<KEY extends keyof typeof settings>({ key, value }: { key: KEY, value: (typeof settings)[KEY]['value'] }) {
    settings[key].value = value;
}

changeSetting({ key: "one", value: true })//ok
changeSetting({ key: "one", value: 'foo' })//error

console.log(settings);
```

Add some meta definition to `SettingsState` to make sure which value type will be used in certain key. And associate value type from `settings` to `changeSetting`.

If you want to keep the key of `settings` same as `key` in that's value:

```js
export type SettingsState<META extends { key: string; type: 'switch' | 'text' }[]> = {
    [key in META[number]['key']]: SingleSetting & {key:key; type: (META[number] & { key: key })['type'] };
}

const settings: SettingsState<
    [
        { key: 'one', type: 'switch' },
        { key: 'two', type: 'text' }
    ]
> = {
    one: {
        title: "1",
        type: "switch",
        value: false,
        key: "one",//ok, only one accepted
    },
    two: {
        title: "2",
        type: "text",
        value: "bad",
        key: "2",//error, only two accepted
    },
};
```

Answer (score 0):

If your `settings` object is fully defined right away you can just define it as it is:

```
export interface SettingsState {
    one: ISettingSwitchType
    two: ISettingTextType
}
...
type SettingsStateKeys = keyof SettingsState

function changeSetting<K extends SettingsStateKeys>({ key, value }: { key: K, value: SettingsState[K]["value"] }) {
    settings[key].value = value;
}

changeSetting({ key: "one", value: "string" }) // Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'boolean'.
```

[TS playground](https://tsplay.dev/wQAMAw)